# How to link my .h and .c files in the same project but different directory using CMake

Tags: eclipse, gcc, cmake

I'm currently working on an embedded C project in Eclipse, cross-compiling to an M4 Cortex target. This project will create 3 separate executable files: apple.hex, orange.hex, and pear.hex. The "apple" source directory compiles, builds, and links without any dependencies on "orange" or "pear". The "orange" source directory also compiles, builds, and links without any dependencies.

However, "pear" needs to access numerous .h and .c assets from "orange". I've had many attempts at getting my CMakeLists.txt to "find" and "link" the code from "orange" to "pear", but to no avail.

Here is my current CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

file(GLOB LD_FILE *gcc_nrf52.ld)


set(MY_APP_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/apps/orange)

create_application(
    NAME
        "pear"
    PLATFORM
        target
    INCLUDE_DIRS
        ./
        ${MY_APP_DIR}
    LINKER_SCRIPT
        ${LD_FILE}
    SOURCES
    ${MY_APP_DIR}/foo.c
    ${MY_APP_DIR}/foo_bar.c
    main.c
LIBRARIES
    SomeLib_1
    SomeLib_2
    SomeLib_3
)
```

However, the compiler keeps complaining, saying that it cannot find "foo.h" and "foo_bar.h".

1) Do I need to separately create a static library in orange in order to access it in pear?

2) If I don't need to create a static library to access orange from pear, how do I link orange to pear?

3) I cannot find where CMake places the object files. Where are they?

This project is all under a single makefile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I was able to fix my directory issues so that all of the include directories in ${MY_APP_DIR} are being linked into "Pear". However, a new issues has arisen. The linker cannot find the map file needed to create the executable image:

**/usr/local/Caskroom/gcc-arm-embedded/5_4-2016q3,20160926/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot open map file /Users/admin/Github/target/apps/pear/pear.map: No such file or directory.**

I'm not sure why a map find isn't being created. Is the linker (ld) still missing files?

Comment: `the compiler keeps complaining, saying that it cannot find "foo.h" and "foo_bar.h".` - Check that these files exist under one of include directory. Probably, they should be under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/apps/orange`. As for other questions - it depends on a way you use  "orange" from "pear". If you just compile some *source* files from "orange" as part of the "pear" executable, you need no library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, what command does my CMakeLists.txt file need in order to "just compile some source files from "orange" as part of the "pear" executable?" Is there any example out there that you can point me to?

Comment: For your "pear" application you list source files `foo.c` and `foo_bar.c` from "orange", don't you? That is what I meant.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yes, I am listing the source files foo.c and foo_bar.c from "orange". I was able to fix my directory mistakes so that the linker can find the source files in "orange". However, now the linker is complaining that is cannot find the map file "pear.map".   " Cannot open pear.map, no such file or directory". My CMakeLists.txt file is still missing some items I suppose.

Comment: As you can see, comments are not suitable for multiline error message: add that message **into the question post** instead (via [edit]). Also, make sure that error message corresponds to the code you have posted (create [mcve]).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, comment fixed, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your questions 
You are not linking your libraries to your target. 
You need something like: 
`$`target_link_libraries(yourtarget yourlibraries) 
after your add_executable command.

3) I cannot find where CMake places the object files. Where are they? 
CMake puts all of its outputs in the build tree by default, so unless you are liberally using ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} or ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} in your cmake files, you should find the output files in the folder where your CMakeLists.txt file is.

Comment: Tiago, given my current set-up, what syntax would be necessary to link certain .c files in "orange" to "pear"?                             
    'add_executable(MAIN main.c)
    find_library(ORANGE orange_foo.a)
    target_link_libraries(MAIN  ORANGE)'